# Selenium Chromedriver error chome not reachable but driver get works

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the page content from a webpage, with the use of selenium and chromedriver. I am using an Ubuntu 18.04 subsystem on Windows. The driver.get method works, but getting the page content does not. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/")

print(driver.page_source)
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "product_tracker.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(driver.page_source)
  File "/home/tychokoster/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 679, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "/home/tychokoster/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/tychokoster/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

Don't really know what to do anymore, I tried changing chromedriver versions, maybe the problem is using a subsystem but I am not sure.

Comment: chrome is installed and runs from wsl bash?

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I am using these version:
ChromeDriver=79.0.3945.16
Chrome=79.0.3945.130
So they should be compatible right

Comment: @pguardiario I have an alias for chrome on windows, and executing the chrome command in the terminal does start up chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with : executable_path with "absolute_path..upto..driver-EXE" not only a directory.

for example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:/Testing Purpose/Pycharm Testing/DemoProject/Driver/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

I have already tested using Pycharm IDE same above code working fine.

Thanks... Enjoy coding...[image]

Comment: Tried it out, with no luck unfortunately! Thanks for the tip tho :)

Comment: Nvm, had to install chromedriver on my windows, instead of on the Ubuntu subsystem. Got it to work with your idea! Thanks man!

Comment: @TychoKoster this help me out with WSL, thanks! We just need to remember to put /mnt/...  driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path='/mnt/c/dev/bin/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', options=options)